# Условие перехода на другую страницу в зависимости от выбранного поля в выпадающем меню

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, стоит задача написать условие на javascript для ситуации, когда пользователь выбирает группу, нажимает кнопку "вперед" и в зависимости от его выбора подтягивается та или иная страничка (например список этой группы).

Я прекрасно понимаю логику работы, но из-за нехватки опыта - проблема такая: я не знаю как подтянуть значение группы (пробовал по ID, почему-то вышло, просидел кучу времени и в итоге решил написать сюда.) и какое значение должна принимать переменная, если, переменная var == 0 для выпадающего списка (может ли она вообще такое значение принимать или должно быть null)

**Напишите пожалуйста корректный вариант и, если не трудно, РАСТОЛКУЙТЕ что да как**,  пересмотрел кучу видео, кучу статей, нашел вариант только такой:

```js
var val = getElementById('one').value;
if val == 0 document.location.href = spisokgryppi.html ';
else alert("Данный код в баззе не хранится!");)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   --
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <h4>Номер группы</h4>
    <select>
       <option disabled>Номер группы</option>
       <option id = "one" >07-16</option>
       <option id = "two" >06-14</option>
       <option id = "three">06-15</option>
      </select>
  </form>

  <form 1> <input type="submit" value="Вперед"> </form 1>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: _Я прекрасно понимаю логику работы_ - опиши ее своими словами

Comment: я должен применить 3 функции, которая будет проверять следующие условия при нажатии на кнопку "Вперед": 1) если val = '1' (т.е. выбрано пользователем) для **id ='one'**, то задается переход на ссылку href = spisokgryppi**1** .html. 2) если val = '1' (т.е. выбрано пользователем) для **id = 'two'**, то задается переход на ссылку href = spisokgryppi**2** .html. 3)  если val = '1' (т.е. выбрано пользователем) для **id = 'three'**, то задается переход на ссылку href = spisokgryppi**3** .html.

Comment: отредактировать вопрос ты можешь с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
  <form>
    <h4>Номер группы</h4>
    <select id="mySelect">
                <option disabled>Номер группы</option>
                <option value="1" >07-16</option>
                <option value="2" >06-14</option>
                <option value="3">06-15</option>
    </select>

  </form>
  <button id="myButton" onClick="myButtonClickHandler()" value="Вперед"></button> 
</body>

function myButtonClickHandler(event) {
  var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
  var value = mySelect.value;
  document.location.href = "spisokgryppi" + value + ".html";
}
```

Условие здесь не нужно, просто по клику на кнопку, берем текущее значение из формы и перенаправляем по сформированной ссылке
Поправил под сценарий описанный в комментарии

Comment: почему не `mySelect.value`?

Comment: @Grundy, да так лучше, поправлю

Comment: Большое спасибо, все оказалось даже проще, чем я думал.

Comment: @GustafHellström Не за что, удачной разработки)